# run script from CLI but prevent running when included

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a php script the I often run using CLI (regular ssh terminal).

```
<?php

    class foo {
        public function __construct() {
            echo("Hello world");
        } 
    }

    // script starts here...
    $bar = new foo();

?>
```

When I run the code using `php filename.php` I get the `Hello world` stagnant as expected. Problem is that when i include the file from other php file I get the same thing (which I don't want).

How can I prevent code from running when file include but still use it as a CLI script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test if `$argv[0] == __FILE__` to see if the file called form the command line is the same as the included file.

```
class foo {
    public function __construct() {

      // Output Hello World if this file was called directly from the command line
      // Edit: Probably need to use realpath() here as well..
      if (isset($argv) && realpath($argv[0]) == __FILE__) {  
        echo("Hello world");
      }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use php function get_included_files and check if your file is in array(using in_array)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that you are BOTH running in the CLI environment AND NOT "included". See my re-write of your sample below:

```
<?php

    class foo {
        public function __construct() {
            echo("Hello world");
        } 
    }

    // script starts here...
    if (substr(php_sapi_name(), 0, 3) == 'cli'
        && basename($argv[0]) == basename(__FILE__) ) {

        // this code will execute ONLY if the run from the CLI
        // AND this file was not "included"
        $bar = new foo();

    }

?>
```